# Перебор массива на Python

Tags: python

Есть такая задача, все работает и проходит. Единственный, вопрос, в чем разница проверки `arr[i]` и просто `i`, так как я в обоих случаях ответ один и тот же

```
def duplicateZeros(arr):
    i = 0 # index position is 0

    while i < len(arr):
        if arr[i] != 0: # тут писал просто i, и все также работало, так в чем их отличие.
            i += 1
        else:
            arr.insert(i+1, 0)
            i += 2
            arr.pop()

    return arr

print(duplicateZeros([1,0,2,3,0,5]))
```

Тут при первом нахождении 0 рядом ставится еще один и происходит сдвиг вправо, но длина массива остается исходной. Я не могу разницу понять между `arr[i]` и просто `i`. Строго не судите, только учусь

Comment: `Я не могу разницу понять между arr[i] и просто i`    `i` - номер квартиры. `arr[i]` - тот, кто живет в этой квартире

Comment: `все работает и проходит` И для   `[1,0,2,0,3,0,5]`?

Comment: @MBo, Спасибо большое! то есть arr[i] - это индекс, а i - это уже сама число, верно?

Comment: i - индекс, arr[i] - элемент списка под данным номером(индексом).  Почему бы книжку не почитать по оcновам языка?

Comment: @MBo то есть `arr[5]`, это 5-й элемент или само число `5` например вот в это списке `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Comment: arr[5] - это число 6

Comment: @MBo Можеье какой-то линк кинуть, где про это вот подробно написано, не понимаю отличий их понять, в том и в ином случае я получаю числа из массива, какая тогда разница. Спасибо

Comment: Ну почитайте какую-нибудь вводную книгу о программировании.Если первый комментарий непонятен, то я уже и не знаю...